# Align center not working for td in table?

Tags: html, css

Here is a simple html table with three rows. I want the button in the last row to align at the center but it is not aligning. I can see slight movement to the right but not perfectly at the center of that row. Am i doing something wrong? Thanks for help!

HTML

```
<div class="search">
    <form action="questions/${id}" method="GET">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="question_id"> <u><b> Question: </b></u> 
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="race_id"> <u><b> Race: </b></u> 
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.search table {
    border: thin solid;
    border-color: #D6D6C2;
}

.search table tr:last-child td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just assign colspan="2" for td [Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/maxspan/cumxz42q/):

```
   <td colspan="2">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your table has 2 columns. However, the button is only in the left column. That's the reason your buttons aligns to center of only the left column and not to the center of the table.

Setting the colspan to 2 for td of last row will expand the cell to 2 columns (and so to width of the table). Now button in td will align to center of the table.

```
<td colspan="2">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use COLSPAN=2 or colspan="2" .

```
 <td colspan="2">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </td>
```

See [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/131Lf7dg/5/).

That should center it perfectly.

In case you're wondering why your code didn't work:

Basically , the `<td>` which contains your button is not taking up 100% of the `<tr>` width , see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/131Lf7dg/8/).

Comment: You mention that COLSPAN=2  would be a valid alternative for colspan="2". While (almost) all browsers support this, it is NOT in any way official HTML. Attribute values should be enclosed by "". This is a syntax rule. And while using capital letters in tags and attribute names is case-insentitive, it is, as far as I know, commonly accepted that one should nromally use lower case letters.

Comment: @HappyMe noted ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do this also.

```
.thirdRow
{
    text-align:center;
}

<tr> 
    <td colspan="2"> 
        <input class="thirdRow" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
<td align="center" colspan="3">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</td>
```